How to add a custom request header to every Next JS server call so it can be read by the middleware.ts
I'm using a session cookie to store a user's role.
And using the middleware.ts to check the role & redirect to an unauthorized page so users can only fetch certain pages.
I'm having an issue where if I login with a differnt user on another tab, its using the previous user's cookie.
Because the original user has not logged out, the cookie remains.
Even if its recreated by the new login, I think the original tab will then use that new cookie gaining roles they should not own.
My idea to solve this was to name the cookie using the oid from a jwt token, so the middleware selects the correct one.
const currentUser = request.cookies.get('currentUser');
// TODO const currentUser = request.cookies.get('currentUser-' + verifyToken(request).oId);

I've seen examples of setting headers in the middleware.ts,
but my understanding is the middleware runs on the next js server.
We are using react MSAL to get a client side token, like msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(etc.).
So I think we need to set the Authorization Bearer ${token} in the header, client side, for every page/router request sent to the next js server.
I've stuggled to find any examples of how to do this.
And I'm not sure if this is the right approach.
I've seen things about custom response headers & rewriting routes, but not about custom request headers in the next js config.
Is my idea possible?
Any advise is much appreciated.
Thank you.
// example
export function middleware(request : NextRequest) {
  const currentUser = request.cookies.get('currentUser');
  // TODO send Authorization header.
  // TODO const currentUser = request.cookies.get('currentUser-' + verifyToken(request).oId);

  if (!isAuthorized(currentUser, request)) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL('/unauthorized', request.url));
  }

  etc...
}

